# Adding text to every second line and remove line break

Tags: notepad++

Using notepad++ I can't get it to work

> 234234
>
> wqeqweqwe
>
> 234234
>
> wqeqweqwe
>
> 234234
>
> wqeqweqwe

Should be like

> 234234:wqeqweqwe
>
> 234234:wqeqweqwe
>
> 234234:wqeqweqwe

but many more

Comment: Well, what are the requirements? What do you mean by "but the whole document"? Do you want to merge all lines into 1 by separating them with `:`?

Comment: have you tried Macros?

Comment: I have multiple examples like the first one i posted in 1 text file and they should all be changed so they look like the second like

Comment: Are there empty lines between the lines you want to merge?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex-based replacement:

Find what: `^(.*)\R(.*)`

Replace With: `$1:$2`

The `^` matches the line start, `(.*)` matches and captures the whole line (Group 1), `\R` matches any linebreak sequence (`\r\n`, `\r` or `\n`), and then the next line is captured into Group 2.

Then the backreferences `$1`and `$2` restore the lines contents and a colon is inserted in between them.

See the screenshot:

[image]